# How to write a reminder mail to a Professor asking about the application?

Tags: professorship, postdocs, email

I have applied to a advertised post for a Postdoctoral position in U.S.A. It's been a month and a half since I have sent the application documents via e-mail to the professor. I haven't received any reply yet. How should I from my reminding e-mail, without offending the professor?

Answer (score 3):

Professors forget to reply to emails all the time. (I think they get trained in email forgetfulness as part of the tenure process) As long as you aren't demanding or insulting, you should be fine. I'd suggest sending something like this:

> Dear Prof. Awesome,
>
> I haven't heard from you since I sent in my Postdoc application on January 3rd. I wanted check on the status of the application and see if there were any other documents you need.
>
> Thank you for your time,
>
> Kunal R Shah